# How do I get next_posts_link to work with private posts?

Tags: private

next_posts_link and previous_posts_link don't show pages or posts that are private. This question has been asked many times on Wordpress forums with no solution. How do I get this navigation to show my privately published posts?

Comment: Do you mean the (next/previous) archive links ?

Comment: Not for archives, necessarily, although they may use the same tag, I can't remember. Specifically, when you're on a single post or single page (or attachment, I believe), the default themes come with a navigation at the bottom with next and previous links to help to go through the posts or pages. However, it skips over pages that are private, even if the user is logged in and able to see private posts or pages.